# web apps AWS migration

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, migration, rds

Working on a project to migrate web applications/sites/mobile apps running drupal on LAMP to AWS. Need advise on best practices and design guidelines for the migration?

Also  need some Best Practices/design considerations  for choosing between S3/EBS, volumes, ELB, MYSQL/RDS for a drupal web applicatio/design conn migration to AWS?

Comment: way too broad of a question. give it a haircut, probably not the best site for this. Try another one on StackExchange

Comment: Hi Drew - To start with looking at the design considerations to choose the correct EC2 instance type for a drupal site hosting about 20 websites.

Comment: [Drupal requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements), and [AWS Instance Types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/). Then ponder actual pounding by users.

Comment: One another good resource for you to start would be to take this training. https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:AWS+OTP-AWSD9+1T2020/course/